# onEdit is not firing when cell containing a formula is updated?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am using onEdit to trigger on a cell value change. But if the cell value is updated because of the formula then onEdit is not working. Any workaround for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No direct solution. as explained here: [GAS-triggers-forumla](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/s5t6MR7fd_U)

the simple triggers only work when a user modifies the sheet. If you want to detect changes in a cell due to a formula, a workaround would be to have a time-based trigger which checks the current value of the cell with the old value, stored as a 'property' of the script/user. In this way it'll know if there'a a change after a fixed amount of time.